# eBay SOAP API - Missing SOA operation name header

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, ebay-api

I am trying to invoke eBay's `findItemsByKeywords` method and I get

> Server raised fault: 'Missing SOA operation name header'

My code is following:

```
from config import *

# url = 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/ebaySvc.wsdl'
# url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/BestMatchItemDetailsService/v1?wsdl'
url = 'http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/finding/latest/FindingService.wsdl'

from suds.client import Client
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
client = Client(url)

from suds.sax.element import Element
ns1 = ('ns1', 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services')
app_id = Element('X-EBAY-API-APP-ID', ns = ns1).setText(EBAY_API_APP_ID)
operation_name = Element('X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME', ns = ns1).setText('findItemsByKeywords')
api_version = Element('X-EBAY-API-VERSION', ns = ns1).setText(EBAY_APP_VERSION)
site_id = Element('X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID', ns = ns1).setText(EBAY_API_SITE_ID)
encoding = Element('X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING', ns = ns1).setText('SOAP')
service_name = Element('X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME', ns = ns1).setText('FindingService')
client.set_options(soapheaders = [app_id, operation_name, api_version, site_id, encoding, service_name]) 

print client.service.findItemsByKeywords(keywords = 'book')
```

It prints:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-API-APP-ID>123456-1234-1234-1234-7876b3f33c3</ns1:X-EBAY-API-APP-ID>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME>findItemsByKeywords</ns1:X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-API-VERSION>721</ns1:X-EBAY-API-VERSION>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID>0</ns1:X-EBAY-API-SITE-ID>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING>SOAP</ns1:X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING>
      <ns1:X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME>FindingService</ns1:X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
         <ns1:keywords>book</ns1:keywords>
      </ns1:findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsdl.py", line 22, in <module>
    print client.service.findItemsByKeywords(keywords = 'book')
  File "/ebay/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/ebay/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/ebay/suds/client.py", line 657, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "/ebay/suds/client.py", line 712, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "/ebay/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Missing SOA operation name header'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [ebay-python, unofficial python wrapper for eBay API](https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay). It's dead easy to use and it works. You can also see the source code on how to construct the request if you want to use your own.

Comment: I need Trading API (AddFixedPriceItem)... There is a note: We won't be implementing Trading API and Large Merchant Services for now.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Will try to implement that method sometime soon.

Comment: It would be great if you implemented it and sent a pull request on github. You can see a reference implementation here: https://github.com/roopeshvaddepally/python-ebay/blob/master/ebay/finding.py

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with some vb.net code trying to do the same thing and it turned out to be that I was simply using the wrong AppID. I was using the live one with the sandbox url, switched it and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it works

```
headers={'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME':'findItemsByKeywords',
                'X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME': 'your-key'}

client = Client(url,headers=headers)
```