# Ebay SOAP error returning "Missing SOA operation name header"

Tags: python, web-services, soap, ebay-api, suds

I'm trying to make some requests on the eBay's webservice using python's [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/), but I always get this error:

> "Missing SOA operation name header"

The code I use is as follows:

```
client = Client(EBAY_WSDL)
ns1 = ('ns1', 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services')
operation_name = Element('X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME',ns=ns1).setText('findItemsByKeywords')
appid = Element('X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME',ns=ns1).setText('MY APP ID')
headers = [appid,operation_name]
client.set_options(soapheaders=headers)
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong with the headers... can someone point it out for me?

Thanks!

--EDIT--

Well, for anyone with the same problem.
I've solved this issue.

The problem is that I'm setting soap header when it should be the http header.
So, the answer is put the headers in the Client constructor, like this:

```
operation_name = {'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME':'findItemsByKeywords', 'SomeOther':'blabla'}
client = Client(EBAY_WSDL,headers=operation_name)
```

That's it!

Comment: Have you checked out this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612425/ebay-soap-api-missing-soa-operation-name-header

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is I don't want to use an wrapper

Comment: See: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1960/~/payout-details-api-is-returning-%22missing-soa-operation-name-header%22-when-making

This is a different set of APIs but here I see that operation name is an element and not text value

Comment: So, the link wasn't very helpful. I'm trying to find an element to represent the operation, but I can't find it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying answer from original poster: brunodea

---

Well, for anyone with the same problem.
I've solved this issue.

The problem is that I'm setting soap header when it should be the http header.
So, the answer is put the headers in the Client constructor, like this:

```
operation_name = {'X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME':'findItemsByKeywords', 'SomeOther':'blabla'}
client = Client(EBAY_WSDL,headers=operation_name)
```

That's it!